# Python, scraping a website for object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program to scrape a monster.com job search and print out all the job titles. When i run it prints nothing, so i added a list range (which is commented out now) to see if the list was populating. It is not. Please let me know what I did wrong.

Here is the code. I'm new to python but to me this should work.

Thanks in advance.

```
    #! /usr/bin/python
import re
import requests
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

webpage = urlopen("http://jobsearch.monster.com/search/Engineer_5?q=Software&where=AZ&rad=20&sort=rv.di.dt").read()

listIterator = []
#listIterator[:] = range(1,50)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)

titleSoup = soup.findAll("title")

for i in listIterator:
    print titleSoup[i]
    print "\n"

raw_input("Press enter to close: ")
```

Comment: You imported `BeautifulSoup` which is great for this, but then you tried to parse the page with regex... why?

Comment: Thanks, pasted the wrong code.

Comment: tried it here and it returned one title tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

handle = urlopen("http://jobsearch.monster.com/search/Engineer_5?q=Software&where=AZ&rad=20&sort=rv.di.dt")
responce = handle.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup( responce )

job_urls = soup.findAll(name = 'a', attrs = { 'class': 'jobTitle fnt11_js' })
for job_url in job_urls:
    print job_url.text
    print
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining job_urls = soup.findAll(name = 'a', attrs = { 'class': 'jobTitle fnt11_js' }) and how that grabbed the titles.

Comment: finding all DOM elements `a` with attribute `class` and creates list of objects `job_urls`. Each object `job_url` has DOM atributes(`job_url['href']`, `job_url['class']`, etc ) and special property text